# NewMailEx - Event not fired on receiving a new email in Office 365

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to create a VSTO in office 365. Ideally NewMailEx delegate is used to handle the incoming messages. But the event is not being fired after receiving a new email in Office 365.

```
this.Application.NewMailEx += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(Application_NewMailEx);
```

Comment: Do you have Outlook (desktop) opened at that time?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: No Eugene. Its closed

Comment: That's the case! Events are fired only when Outlook is running.

Answer (score 0):

The [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171304(v=office.11).aspx) is not fired if multiple items are received at the same time. You can use a timer and track items changes as a possible workaround. Or use low-level notifications available in Extended MAPI. Read more about possible solutions in the following series of articles:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)

Comment: Even for single item the event is not fired. What i observed is the delegate "ApplicationEvents_11_newMailEXhandler" is not recognized. "Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'ApplicationEvents_11_newMailEXhandler' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook' (are you missing an assembly reference?) What could be the possible reason please

Comment: Do you get any design-time errors in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the root cause. The addin is added to outlook as disabled addin. And local proximity team restricted the disabled addins.

Solutions - Changed the assemdly name